# Get line count of a specific column and get the value of that specific column using row number

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datatable

python, pandas read from csv file.

How do I get only TMI value from a specific row?

I mean by using ROW and single INDEX or COLUMN,

Like only get TMI 17 or 20 value
and see how many TMI is there and get TMI line count.

```
import pandas as pd
with open('./Essentials/test2.csv','r') as f:
    weather_df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

```
STAT,NAME,DATE,TA,TM,TMI
test123,"ASDDD",10115,23,29,17
test123,"ASDDD",20115,23,29.2,20
test123,"ASDDD",30115,24,29.9,20
test123,"ASDDD",40115,23,26.1,13
test123,"ASDDD",50115,20,23.7,18
test123,"ASDDD",60115,20,24.3,13
test123,"ASDDD",70115,17,22.5,13
test123,"ASDDD",80115,17,22.9,12
test123,"ASDDD",90115,18,23.3,13
test123,"ASDDD",100115,19,13.2,13
test123,"ASDDD",110115,16,21,11
test123,"ASDDD",120115,19,24.5,11
test123,"ASDDD",130115,18,26.5,12
test123,"ASDDD",150115,18,28.1,13
,"ASDDD",160115,21,28,14.2
,"ASDDD",170115,18,24,
,"ASDDD",180115,14,16,
,,190115,14,13,
,,200115,15,18,
```

csv file, here I want to get, STAT has 14 rows or NAME has 17 lines, Then call the Value, suppose call "TMI" line 8 value and put it into variable

Comment: you're looking for `loc` or `iloc` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get a value of a specific cell

```
weather_df.at[row index, 'column name']
```

for example the following will give you a value of `17`

```
weather_df.at[0, 'TMI']
```

to get the number of cells excluding NaN use `.count()`

```
weather_df.['TMI'].count()
```

without specifying a column it will return the non-Nan row count for each column individually

Comment: And about "Length" cause it also takes NaN as data and also count NaN

Comment: @WoLvES2.0 I've edited the answer according to your question

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should work:

```
tmi_rows = df.loc[(df.TMI == 17) | (df.TMI == 20)]
print(tmi_rows)
```

Comment: can't accept 2 answer!!! but I accepted 2 answer, cuz I needed 2 of em